# How to modify panel in Ubuntu[unity] 16.04?

Tags: unity

I want to edit panel of Ubuntu. I already have Unity Tweak tool but it changes color or make transparent. But I want to edit more like in a MAC OS X panel.

Comment: Try this. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-5-steps and you might also want the Cairo-Dock.

Comment: First of all it's for Gnome Desktop Environment and second i already did that in unity DE . But i want to add more options in panels